# How do I select all points that lie within a layer's bounding box?

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS to do this. I have a mesh created from the v.trimesh tool. I want to find all the points that lie in the bounds of a layer. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to find the points that lie within the triangles of your mesh? If not, please provide a sketch.

Answer (score 2):

You have three options as I see it, from your question:

1. You want points within the triangles of your mesh as suggested by underdark:
   Go to either Vector->Research Tools->Select by location and complete the dialog box options appropriately, OR, go to PlugIns->Spatial Query and select appropriate options there.
2. You want points that lie within the extent of all the triangles.
   Go to Vector->Polygon from layer extent and make a polygon of the full extent.  Then follow the steps in option 1 above using your new polygon.
3. You want points that lie within the sum of all your triangles (like option 2 but excluding those areas not covered by triangles.
   Do option 1 - it's the same thing but just phrased differently

From the way you phrase the question, I think you want option 2 but without clarification I'm not sure.

Hope this helps